# using @include inside inline element in jade/pug template

Tags: html, templates, include, pug

is their a way to include an external document at compile time inline and inside a tag with text using jade/pug templating?

for example, something like:

```
p paragraph text content with #[span.icon @include path_to_file/icon.svg] inline svg thrown into the html document
```

but not this solution:

```
p paragraph text content with #[span.icon #[svg #[use(href='path_to_file/icon.svg')]]]
```

i know the later works, but i'm looking for a solution that doesn't use the use tag or an external reference

solution needs to result in importing the document inside the tag in between the words at compile time.

i've looked through the pug documentation many times. only things close to this are tag interpolation and block expansion, but they don't seem to allow for this situation specifically.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the vertical bar without having to use string interpolation:

```
p
  | paragraph text content with 
  span.icon 
    include path_to_file/icon.svg
  | inline svg thrown into the html document
```

See tag interpolation here: https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html